# Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am working on trying to split my doubly linked list. But i get nullpointer exception on sublist.head = mid.next. Does it means sublist.head is pointing to null? How can i resolve this??

```
public void splitMid(DoublyLinkedList<T> sublist)
{
    Node<T> current;
    Node<T> mid;
    int i;
    if (head == null)
    {
        sublist.head = null;
        sublist.rear = null;
        sublist.count = 0;
    }
    else
        if (head.next == null)
        {
            sublist.head = null;
            sublist.rear = null;
            sublist.count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            mid = head;
            current = head.next;
            i = 1;
            if (current != null)
                current = current.next;
            while (current != null)
            {
                mid = mid.next;
                current = current.next;
                i++;
                if (current != null)
                    current = current.next;
            }
            sublist.head = mid.next;
            sublist.rear = rear;
            rear = mid;
            rear.next = null;
            sublist.count = count - i;
            count = i;
        }

}
```

Comment: Unless you are working on this in order to learn how to implement a double linked list, I would suggest you use `LinkedList` instead, which is a double linked list...

Answer (score 2):

If this statement:

```
 sublist.head = mid.next;
```

(taken in isolation) is throwing an NPE, it means that:

- `sublist` is `null`, OR
- `mid` is `null`, OR
- both of them are `null`.

(You could figure out which with either a debugger & conditional breakpoints, or by adding some temporary trace prints or assertions.)

Comment: I thought (a || b) covers the (a && b) case already... Why so explicit? :)

Comment: 'cos I'm a pedant ... and OR is not a Java operator :-)

Comment: Am i right to think that previous is not needed here as it is splitting hence it is just next

Comment: 1)  I don't understand what you are saying.  2) I haven't analysed your code.  I am simply telling you that there are TWO possible reasons why that statement could throw an NPE.  (Figuring out what the real problem is, and correcting it is .... your homework, not mine.)